# Multiple PathParams not failing when the first one in Path is missing

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a path that takes two mandatory path params. When the second param is included but the first is excluded my service is hit where I would expect a 404 as the URI is invalid.

```
@GET
@Path("service/{param1}/{param2}")
public Response getSuppliersBySupplierCode(@PathParam("param1") String param1, @PathParam("param2") String param2) {

        //do something
}
```

I would expect a 404 in each of the below 3 scenarios but the second two work.

`..../service//` -> fails with 404

`..../service/param/` -> hits my service

`..../service//param2` -> hits my service

Why do I not get a 404 in scenario 2 and 3 here? I would expect it to fail as one of my two params is missing

Comment: In case 2 and 3 do you get Internal Server Error ?

Comment: No it hits the service and it is handled by internal validation. I would expect a 404 with multiple params as is the case with a single.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the 2nd and 3rd scenarios work is that by default the path variables are matched against `[^/]+?` which means that they will match empty strings. You can change the regex that does the matching by adding a colon and then the regex, like this `{param1: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]}`. See [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html) for more details.

Comment: I've tried adding separate regex for each param but i'm getting the same results. Regex used was [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9-]. Allowing for alphanumeric and -